# Selecting multiple elements with a single pseudo class?

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I am creating something and need to save a couple of bytes, take the following code:

```
button:focus, input[type=submit]:focus, .btn:focus {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Can I do something like:

```
button, input[type=submit], .btn:focus {
    /* Styles */
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can't...not yet....although it's coming (eventually).